# Jquery Updation error

Tags: jquery

[image][image]

After updating to jquery latest version i am getting the error in the screenshot. Please suggest.

Comment: which version did you use beforehand?

Comment: I belive new jQuery 1.9 no longer supports .toggle - so if you have that in your code, that might be the reason for one of your errors.

Comment: Can you post the jquery you use on that page?

Answer (score 0):

The huge jump in versions evidentially caused a headache, if possible in future update as soon as possible after reading each version's **release notes** to check for changes.

That being said it looks as though you're using an outdated selector or three, update lines such as:

```
...@rel=...
```

To:

```
...rel=...
```

The `@` symbol is no longer required. The same goes for any other selectors that use element attributes.

Comment: Yeah, kind like going from Windows 95 to Windows 7 and expecting all the old programs will still work.

Comment: Well, not only is it no longer required, but the syntax has been completely removed: "Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again." from http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/